# Passing a class object into a templated classes private member scope

Tags: c++

Hi I'm new to c++ and trying to learn something. maybe it can't be done. but I want to:

- create an Employee class that records all employees, and their information (see my code below).
- Then I want to make a templated class for a linked list. inside the private scope of this class, I will have a "T data" type. I want my constructor to instantiate an "Employee" every time a LinkedList object is created in the main. I hope that makes sense. I have my code working the way I set it up now. However, I'm not necessarily templating it the way I want.

```
template <class T>
class Employees { //Parent
private:
    int EmployeeID;
    double Paycheck;
    int Hours;
    double Payrate;
    std::string Employeename;
public:
    Employees(int ID, double Prate, std::string EName) {
        EmployeeID = ID;
        Payrate = Prate;
        Employeename = EName;
        Hours = 0; //our constructor can just give each Employee 0 hours.
        Paycheck = 0.00;
    }
    Employees() {
        EmployeeID = 0;
        Payrate = 0.0;
        Employeename = "N/A";
        Hours = 0;
        Paycheck = 0.00;
    }
    void setPaycheck() {
        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
        double i = Payrate;
        i = i * 100;
        i = i * Hours;
        i = i / 100;
        Paycheck = i;
        //so I'm not sure why I couldn't just cast the double, but the complier kept rounding down each time.
        // I had to make a conversion of my decimal into a whole number and then go back and divide it to get the
        // paycheck amount.
    };
    void setEMPname(std::string Name) {
        Employeename = Name;
    }
    void setPayrate(double payrate) {
        Payrate = payrate;
    }
    void setEMPid(int IDnum) {
        EmployeeID = IDnum;
    }
    void setHOURS(int hours) {
        Hours += hours;
    }
    int IDReturn() { return EmployeeID; }
    int HoursReturn() { return Hours; }
    double PaycheckReturn() { return Paycheck; }
    double PayrateReturn() { return Payrate; }
    std::string NameReturn() { return Employeename; }
};

template <class T>
class LinkedLists :Employees<T> { //child
    friend class Employees<T>;
private:
////I want change the object below to "T data"
    Employees<T> EmployeeObject; //contains all the employee information 
    LinkedLists<T>* nextlink;
    LinkedLists<T>* prevlink;
public:
    LinkedLists() {
        EmployeeObject;
        nextlink = nullptr;
        prevlink = nullptr;
    }
    void setname(std::string Name) {
        EmployeeObject.setEMPname(Name);
    }
    void setPrate(double payrate) {
        EmployeeObject.setPayrate(payrate);
    }
    void setid(int IDnum) {
        EmployeeObject.setEMPid(IDnum);
    }
    void setPayCheck() { EmployeeObject.setPaycheck(); }
    LinkedLists<T>*& setLinkforward() {
        return nextlink;
    }
    LinkedLists<T>*& setLinkbackward() {
        return prevlink;
    }
    int idReturn() { return EmployeeObject.IDReturn(); }
    double payrateReturn() { return EmployeeObject.PayrateReturn(); }
    std::string nameReturn() { return EmployeeObject.NameReturn(); }
    void AddHours(int Hours) { EmployeeObject.setHOURS(Hours); }
    int ReturnHours() { return EmployeeObject.HoursReturn(); }
    double ReturnPayCheck() {

        return EmployeeObject.PaycheckReturn();
    }

};
```

Comment: _"However, I'm not necessarily templating it the way I want."_ - What do you mean? I don't understand your question.

Comment: A `template` is not a `class` -- it is not itself a type.  A `template class` is a bit of code that makes `class`s.  It is a factory that produces types.  `Employees` is a class -- a type.  When you type `Employees<T>` you are using it as if `Employees` was a template.  It is not a template.  There are also grammar errors; `Employees` -- why is that **plural**?  It contains info about one employee, not multiple.

Comment: Your inheritance also doesn't make sense: `class LinkedLists :Employees<T>`.  `LinkedList<T>` isn't an `Employee`, it **has** an `Employee`.  Finally, why is `LinkedList` a template at all?  `T` is supposed to be a parameter to the type-function that produces the actual linked list; you don't use it.  Did you mean `LinkedList<Employee>`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Now `Employees` is a class template :-) It was apparently an editing error that churill fixed. `Gazeeb0:` What you've created are classes connected through [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). This can be handy  in some situations but a linked list is _usually_ pretty type agnostic and doesn't care about the type in the list. I suggest not making `Employee` a template until you see a need for it and make your linked list work with any type, not just `Employee`.

Comment: WOW, I can't believe I got responses so quickly. @Ted Lyngnmo. Thank you all so much.

Yes, that was a typo on my end. Ted, you explained it much better than I ever could, essentially, I want to make my 'LinkedList's Employees<T> EmployeeObject' into 'T data' which means it can take the type of data, and still perform the operation needed for linking, etc. However, when I create a constructor that attempts to make 'T data' an Employees object I get an error that says "Field has incomplete type 'T'".
I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong. Thank you, everyone, for the responses.

Comment: @Gazeeb0 You're welcome :) Comments and/or answers often come really quickly here. As for the error you get, since you haven't gotten any real answers, only comments, you could update your question (including the code that goes with it) to reflect that situation instead.